# expandablelistview with jsonarray object in android

Tags: android

Hi i have a json response object like this.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Forbes",
        "guid": "aa8ee769628871feea7081e8c9b9ac1a",
        "id": "1",
        "region": "U.S National Publications",
        "state": "US"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Oregonian",
        "guid": "f0511e35b43241c641921221efcc4ae8",
        "id": "2",
        "region": "U.S Local Publications",
        "state": "Oregon"
    },
    {
        "name": "Chicago Tribune",
        "guid": "fcbfc403c4131b3361bf2ebeee2a743d",
        "id": "3",
        "region": "U.S Local Publications",
        "state": "Illinois"
    },
    {
        "name": "Detroit Free Press",
        "guid": "dc2e708f3d2d09b0f082cb1550535b99",
        "id": "4",
        "region": "U.S Local Publications",
        "state": "Michigan"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Philadelphia Inquirer",
        "guid": "23df2f82e304a7bd2f2b0a8f68a983a4",
        "id": "5",
        "region": "U.S Local Publications",
        "state": "Pennsylvania"
    }
]
```

here "region" is the group and "name" is child .can anyone help how to display this in android code.for expandable listview in android.group should be a dropdown child should be checkedtextview.

Comment: How you want to show?? means that . What should be header and when expandable list view expand . What should be in expanded list

Comment: Parse this json into an hashmap where region will be the keys and name will be the values.. pass this hashmap to the adapter and use hashmap keyset as group item and their values as child items.

Comment: region should be the group name in expandablelistview and name should be the childs to that expandable listview.any tuotials suggested to get expandablelistview dynamically with json array object?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HashMap with String as key and ArrayList HashMap as value :

```
        String jsonResponse ="[{\"name\":\"Forbes\",\"guid\":\"aa8ee769628871feea7081e8c9b9ac1a\",\"id\":\"1\",\"region\":\"U.S National Publications\",\"state\":\"US\"},{\"name\":\"The Oregonian\",\"guid\":\"f0511e35b43241c641921221efcc4ae8\",\"id\":\"2\",\"region\":\"U.S Local Publications\",\"state\":\"Oregon\"},{\"name\":\"Chicago Tribune\",\"guid\":\"fcbfc403c4131b3361bf2ebeee2a743d\",\"id\":\"3\",\"region\":\"U.S Local Publications\",\"state\":\"Illinois\"},{\"name\":\"Detroit Free Press\",\"guid\":\"dc2e708f3d2d09b0f082cb1550535b99\",\"id\":\"4\",\"region\":\"U.S Local Publications\",\"state\":\"Michigan\"},{\"name\":\"The Philadelphia Inquirer\",\"guid\":\"23df2f82e304a7bd2f2b0a8f68a983a4\",\"id\":\"5\",\"region\":\"U.S Local Publications\",\"state\":\"Pennsylvania\"}]";

        HashMap<String,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> regionsHashMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                if(regionsHashMap.containsKey(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("region"))){
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> regionList = regionsHashMap.get(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("region"));
                    HashMap<String,String> regionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    regionMap.put("name",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    regionMap.put("guid",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("guid"));
                    regionMap.put("id",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                    regionMap.put("region",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("region"));
                    regionMap.put("state",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("state"));
                    regionList.add(regionMap);
                    regionsHashMap.put(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("region"),regionList);
                }else{
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> regionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    HashMap<String,String> regionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    regionMap.put("name",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                    regionMap.put("guid",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("guid"));
                    regionMap.put("id",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                    regionMap.put("region",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("region"));
                    regionMap.put("state",jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("state"));
                    regionList.add(regionMap);
                    regionsHashMap.put(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("region"),regionList);
                }
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator it = regionsHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println("Region :: "+pairs.getKey());
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> regionList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) pairs.getValue();
            for(HashMap<String,String> region : regionList){
                System.out.println("name : "+region.get("name"));
                System.out.println("guid : "+region.get("guid"));
                System.out.println("id : "+region.get("id"));
                System.out.println("region : "+region.get("region"));
                System.out.println("state : "+region.get("state"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: any tutorial to get expandablelistview dynamically with json?

Comment: i dont want to show the respose like this in code i jus want to give a plain url where i get the response and the UI should be a expandablelistview with subitems where "region" as parent or group name and "name" should be the subitem or a child in expandablelistview in android.any tutorial?

Answer (score -1):

```
YOU CAN USE JSON LIKE THIS 

**This is HomeFragment java class**

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
        private static String url = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt";
        private ProgressDialog mprocessingdialog;
        private TextView tv_welcomeuser, tv_recentupdate;
        private ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
        private ExpandableListView exp_leaseoffer;
        private List<String> listDataHeader;
        private View rootView;
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wellcome_page, container, false);
            tv_welcomeuser = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_welcomeuser);
            tv_recentupdate = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_recentupdate);

            exp_leaseoffer = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            new DownloadJason().execute();

            return rootView;
        }

        private class DownloadJason extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                mprocessingdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                mprocessingdialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
                mprocessingdialog.setMessage("Loading");
                mprocessingdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mprocessingdialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
                String jsonstr = jp.makeServiceCall(url, JSONParser.GET);
                Log.d("Json url view", jsonstr);

                if (jsonstr != null) {

                    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                        JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
                        for (int hk = 0; hk < jarray.length(); hk++) {
                            JSONObject d = jarray.getJSONObject(hk);
                            // Adding Header data

                            listDataHeader.add(d.getString("country"));
                            // Adding child data for lease offer
                            List<String> lease_offer = new ArrayList<String>();

                            lease_offer.add(d.getString("country") + "'s Rank is : "
                                    + d.getString("rank"));
                            lease_offer.add("And Population is "+d.getString("population"));
                            // Header into Child data
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(hk), lease_offer);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Please Check internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                mprocessingdialog.dismiss();

                expandableListAdapter = new info.tranetech.adurec.fragments.Expandable_adapter(
                        getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                Log.i("groups", listDataHeader.toString());
                Log.i("details", listDataChild.toString());
                exp_leaseoffer.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

                exp_leaseoffer.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }

                });
                // Listview Group expanded listener
                exp_leaseoffer
                        .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                                // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                // listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                exp_leaseoffer
                        .setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                                + " Collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
                exp_leaseoffer.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        // Toast.makeText(
                        // getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        // listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                        // + " : "
                        // + listDataChild.get(
                        // listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        // childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        // .show();

    //                  Intent ilk = new Intent(getActivity(),
    //                          Lease_Offer_one.class);
    //                  startActivity(ilk);

                        return false;
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        // public Boolean isWifiAvailable() {
        //
        // try {
        // ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        // getActivity()
        // .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager
        // .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        //
        // if (wifiInfo.isConnected()) {
        // return true;
        // }
        // } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }
        // return false;
        // }

        // public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        // ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        // getActivity()
        // .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
        // .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        // }

    }

    **This is Expandable_adapter java class**




    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Expandable_adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader;
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public Expandable_adapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
            }
            TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_listchild);
            expandedListTextView.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }
            TextView listTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_listtitle);
            listTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            listTitle.setText(headerTitle);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
**xml wellcome_page**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_welcome" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_welcomeuser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="WELCOME USER"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eeeee"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_welcomeuser"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recentupdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="RECENT UPDATES"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eeeee"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textLin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_adurec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="times_roman"
                android:text="   Powered by "
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,HardcodedText,SpUsage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_adurec"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ADUREC"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,HardcodedText" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textLin"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/buttons_effacts"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="0.8dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

**list_child.xml **
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_listchild"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#7D1023"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

**list_group.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_listtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_effacts"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```